# How to omit the port number when running a Node.js Docker container

Tags: docker, http, url, docker-compose

I have a simple Node.js server application which I have containerized.

The Node.js server runs on port 3000 so it answers at URL `http://localhost:3000`.

In another application I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which pull the Node.js app image and run it, like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  myserver:
    container_name: myserver_nodejs
    image: registry.gitlab.com/cs-repos/work/myserver:v1.0.2-latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

It pulls the image from GitLab container registry, locally, and runs the container.

### Issue:

In order to make a request to the server I need to add the port number like this: `localhost:3000`, then the path.

**I wonder, is there a way so that the `docker-compose.yml` handles the port for me, so that I don't have to use it in my requests?**

So to make a request like this: `http://localhost/sales`, and internally the request goes to port 3000.

Also i added a record in the `/etc/hosts`:

- `127.0.0.1 my.server.com`.

Instead of using the `localhost`, I can use the mapped address `my.server.com` but I need the port number at the end as well.

The ports property just makes a mapping between the host and the container, it is needed but it's not solving the issue:

```
 ports:
     - 3000:3000
```

Comment: This seems like the same question as [How to access a Docker container without specifying its HTTP port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226750/how-to-access-a-docker-container-without-specifying-its-http-port)

Comment: hi, i read it. The main consept is the same, but for my case i cant use the default port 80, because it is used by another service. I think that traefik can solve that, but i dont know how, yet. :)

Comment: If you have an `http://...` URL without a port number it goes to port 80, and your host only has one port 80, so you'll have to resolve that conflict somehow.  If your service isn't running on port 80 then you need to include the different port number in the URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a Docker container without specifying its HTTP port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226750/how-to-access-a-docker-container-without-specifying-its-http-port)

Answer (score 2):

Albeit the question is phrased in terms of `docker-compose.yml`, the standard answer actually has not much to do with Docker:

#### HTTP → 80

If you're relying on the HTTP protocol, which has 80 as default port, you will be able to connect to the server with a "port-free" URL **if it listens to port 80**.

Then, in terms of Docker Compose, one could write:

```yaml
ports:
  - "80:3030"
```

then browsing `http://localhost` should work.

#### HTTPS → 443

If you're relying on HTTPS / TLS, which has 443 as default port, you will be able to connect to the server with a "port-free" URL **if it listens to port 443**.

So, one could write:

```yaml
ports:
  - "443:3030"
```

then browsing `https://localhost` should work (assuming the container can serve resources in HTTPS).

#### Remark on HTTPS

Note that **if your Docker Compose service is not TLS-aware,** a typical solution amounts to completely removing the `ports:` invocation for that service, make it serve in HTTP, and put in front of this service a (dockerized) TLS termination proxy.

For more details on this architecture, see e.g. these two older answers of mine:

- [Connection error in apps when enabling https on example.com:8080 (Docker) with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971039/9164010)
- [Implement LetsEncrypt in Spring Boot app that is being pulled by docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904111/9164010)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, FYI i cant use port 80 because it is already used by another service. I assume `traefik` will give me the solution, but i need to read deeper how it works and how to configure it..